# Using bootstrap template with vanilla web components

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, web-component

I have a traditional ASP.NET MVC web site, that uses the Metronic Bootstrap template.

Now, I'm thinking of rewriting this web site using the vanilla web components approach.

So I did a small test, and wrote a web component without shadow dom, and it seems my component just uses the Metronic style fine, so it inherits it from the parent page where I included it.

However, when I enable shadow DOM, then CSS propagation stops, and now my web component is not using the Metronic style anymore.

At this time I'm a bit uncertain on how to handle this situation: I can simply not use shadow DOM, but then, I'm not using the full strength and encapsulation of web components.

So how would you handle the situation where you have a large Bootstrap template that you want to use, in combination with web components? Is it worth it? Are there guidelines for this kind of situation?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you need to use a large CSS framework within ShadowDOM based Web Components then you need to include that CSS in each component or, at least, the portion of CSS needed for that component.

ShadowDOM was designed to prevent outside CSS from affecting the inner ShadowDOM. So, if you want specific CSS inside the ShadowDOM then you have to put it there.

The simplest thing to do is to include the `<link>` tag in your ShadowDOM. The same `<link>` tag you used outside of the components.

```js
class MyElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    let shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    shadow.innerHTML = `
    <link href="my.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <h2 class="my-header">My Component</h2>
    <button class="my-button">Pay me</button>`;
  }
}

customElements.define('my-element', MyElement);
```

```html
<link href="my.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="my-thing">Stuff</div>
<button class="my-button">Click me</button>
<hr/>
<my-element></my-element>
```

Since I don't have a file `my.css` you won't see the changes.

This will allow you to include the CSS in your page and also in your Components.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, I read this. But my conclusion on this one was that it would probably slow down the site a lot because those dependencies are downloaded each time. Is that correct?

Comment: The browsers are pretty smart and the linked CSS file is only downloaded once and then used everywhere. As far as I know it is not even replicated, just used in each place.

Comment: Hm, interesting... ok, thanks, I'll experiment a bit more then! I guess that with javascript required by Metronic, it's the same principle? Link to it in the same way as with the css files?

Comment: JS is different. If the JS file is loaded once you don't need to load it again. shadowDOM only creates a sandbox for the DOM and CSS and _not_ for the JS. The way that JS can be loaded only once is by using ES6 `import`: https://devdocs.io/javascript/statements/import But that is not supported in older browsers and can not be polyfilled. If you don't use `import` and your components are only going to work in an enviroment with Metronic, then the page should load the Metronic JS files and the components will just use them. It does mean that your components can not be used without Metronic.

Comment: *Continuing from my previous comment:* The only JS that is directly related to the component is what you place in the component class and any helper functions you add to the JS file that defines your component.